# removing child elements if api returns null array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am calling my local API which returns the list of products while onchange event is triggered.

i am also creating new option element for each array and setting name and value to it. the created element is appended on select element.

but the problem is. for example 1st call returns 1 array and the second call to api returns 2 arrays.

so on second call 3 option elements will be rendered on form while it should be only 2 option elements.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="productForm" 
  th:action="@{/addProduct}" method="post">


    <div class="form-group">
        <div th:if="${productAdded}">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <p>Product added successfully</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Category:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                <option th:name="category"  th:each="cat : ${categories}" 
                th:value="${catth:text="${cat.category}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="productName">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" >
        <select  class="form-control" id="productName"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Product Price" name="price" id="price">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Quantity:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Vendor:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Product Vendor" name="vendor" id="vendor">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AddProduct.js**

```
//adding event listener to category select box
document.getElementById("category")
.addEventListener('change',getProductDetails);
let products = document.getElementById("productName");
let prodPrice = document.getElementById("price");
let prodVendor = document.querySelector("#vendor");
let productForm = document.querySelector('#productForm');
console.log(productForm);


function getProductDetails() {
    let category = document.getElementById("category").value;
    fetch("
    http://localhost:6080/getProductDetailsByCategory?category="+category)
        .then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    if(data ==null || data.length ==0){
            refresh();
    }

    data.forEach(function (t) {
        let optionBox = document.createElement("option");
        console.log(t.productName);
        optionBox.text=t.productName;
        optionBox.value= t.productName;
        products.appendChild(optionBox);

    });

})
}

function refresh(){
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: you have written code for appendtoDom; where is your code for removefromDOM; On new api request, find the prev inserted elements into dom and remove them;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the select element then insert all those options came as the result of the api call. I guess you are not getting only the new records as the response but getting all the records, hence remove every option and then insert all. In the .then section of code, write this.

```
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
if(data ==null || data.length ==0){
   refresh(); // Instead of refreshing the page
}
// clear the select element first 
products.innerHTML = "";

data.forEach(function (t) {
    let optionBox = document.createElement("option");
    console.log(t.productName);
    optionBox.text=t.productName;
    optionBox.value= t.productName;
    products.appendChild(optionBox);

});
```

})